# How to copy to clipboard a Markdown formatted string using Swift?

Tags: swift, markdown, nsattributedstring

I'm using the `MarkdownUI` library and through it I can create a markdown rendering as follows:

```swift
let someText = "
# Title

## Description

## Tables

| Left columns  | Right columns |
| ------------- |:-------------:|
| left foo      | right foo     |
| left bar      | right bar     |
| left baz      | right baz     |
"

let markdownString: String = MarkdownContent(someText).renderMarkdown()
```

I want to copy the rendered markdown text and be able to paste as in the image that follows and not the raw text as I've gotten that contains `#`, `**`, `|`, etc.

[image]

I tried this:

```swift
NSPasteboard.general.clearContents()
NSPasteboard.general.setString(markdownString, forType: .string)
```

But I was not successful. I also tried this:

```swift
let markdownString: String = MarkdownContent(someText).renderMarkdown()
let attrStr: AttributedString = AttributedString(markdownString)
let nsAttributedString: NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(attrStr)
                            
let documentAttributes = [NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.wordML]
let range: NSRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: nsAttributedString.length)
let rtfData = try nsAttributedString.data(from: range, documentAttributes: documentAttributes)
                            
NSPasteboard.general.clearContents()
NSPasteboard.general.setData(rtfData, forType: .rtf)
```

In all cases I get the pure string. When I paste it into the Notes app for example, I have this:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

**Note**: I'm using this library because it's the only one that can support `SwiftUI`, using two or more libraries for markdown seems to be impossible due to the duplicate dependencies the libraries have. Using native markdown doesn't solve my problems, because it doesn't support headers and tables.

Comment: Why do you create data for `.wordML` but then paste is as `rtf`? The two types should match.

Comment: The problem is not with your library. You don't even need the library. `AttributedString` and `NSAttributedString` can be created with `someText` directly. The problem seems to be related to the fact that the resulting `NSAttributedString` doesn't have "normal" attributes. It has a series of `NSPresentationIntent` instances. And only when created via markup. Those "intents" don't get copied over into the pasteboard. Maybe there's some API that converts the "intents" into specific attributes. Then putting it in the pasteboard should work.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot for your comment. In this case the library I'm using is not capable of providing these "intents" to the clipboard. When you say the `NSAttributedString` could be created directly, are you sure it can handle tables in markdown formatting? Because I'm using the library for exactly that reason.

Comment: If you do `let nsAttr = try! NSAttributedString(markdown: someText)` and then `print(nsAttr)` you can see references to table layout. I just don't know how to deal with the `NSPresentationIntent` with regard to putting the string in the pasteboard.